# How to access variables within a component rendered in App.js

Tags: reactjs

I created a Form.js component that handles my form and I render it in App.js and was wondering how to access the variables such as videoURL, start, and end from Form.js in App.js. I saw another post about using props where when you render like this `<Form videoURL={videoURL} start={start} end={end}/>`, but ran into 'videoUrl', 'start', and 'end' being undefined.

This is my Form.js file,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Form extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             video_url: '',
             start: 0,
             end: 0

        }
    }

    handleVideoUrlChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            videoURL: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleStartChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            start: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleEndChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            end: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
    }
    
    render() {
        const { videoURL, start, end } = this.state
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method="post">
                <div>
                    <label>Video URL</label>
                    <input type="text" value={videoURL} onChange={this.handleVideoUrlChange}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Start</label>
                    <input type="number" value={start} onChange={this.handleStartChange}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>End</label>
                    <input type="number" value={end} onChange={this.handleEndChange}/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>

        )
    }
}

export default Form
```

This is my App.js file,

```
import React , {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Form from "./Form";

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/test')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setData(data))
    }, []);
   
    return (
        <>
        <Form videoURL={videoURL} start={start} end={end}/>
        <div className="container">
            <h2>Top Users</h2>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>User</th>
                        <th># of Messages</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        data.map((item, i) => (
                            <tr key={item.user}>
                                <td>{i + 1}</td>
                                <td>{item.user}</td>
                                <td>{item.messages}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Also, once I am able to access these variables, I am trying to do a POST request within App.js to the backend, do some work, and then return the results. Would it be something along the lines like this?

```
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/test'),
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    'videoURL': videoURL,
                    'start': start,
                    'end': end
                })
            }
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setData(data))
    }, []);
```

Comment: So App.js is your parent component and you want to access these variables there ?

Comment: If `App` is rendering `Form` then it won't have access to `Form`'s state. See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to move the state to the common ancestor, i.e. move the state to `App` and pass as props to `Form` as you mention seeing in another post. Data flows in one direction in React, parent to child component.

Comment: First option is to move the state to the parent (App.js) or second option is to make global state using Redux or useContext from react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to access the childrens state from a parent component. Here is a way .

#### STEP 1:

First you need to add a function in your App.js file to receive data from your children component.  in App.js

```
const [videoUrl , setVideoUrl] = useState('')

const  receiveVideoUrlFromChildren = (videoUrlFromChildren) => {
   setVideoUrl(videoUrlFromChildren)
}
```

#### STEP 2:

Then pass this function to your children component. So inside your App.js return add this.

```
<Form sendDataToParent=(receiveVideoUrlFromChildren) />
```

#### STEP 3:

Whenever the value changes in Children pass the data back to the parent by calling this function. Inside Form.js

```
handleVideoUrlChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        videoURL: event.target.value
    })
    this.props.sendDataToParent(event.target.value)
}
```

So Now you can access the data from your Parent component. You can do this 3 times. for 3 variables . or use one function to send all the data as an object.

Comment: Thank you so much for the step by step tutorial.